# Mule - route depending on json payload

Tags: mule, anypoint-studio

I'm running Mule CE 3.8 and need to route my messages depending on a value in the JSON payload.
I get a list of JSON from a REST endpoint which runs through a JSON2ObjectList and a collection splitter.

```
    <http:request ... /> 
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="JSON2ObjectList"/>
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
    <custom-transformer ../>
```

Now before the CustomTransformer and all the mapping I need to have a choice router that separates the messages depending on the payloads *Product.Warehouse* value. I was thinking of a Java component that could set a flow variable to the value of the Warehouse field but maybe there is an easier way to solve this?
I looked into MEL and expression transformers but couldn't figure that one out.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put choice router before CustomTransformer and put check on payload.warehouse. As collection splitter will produce your Product Object. You can directly access its properties.

Something like

```
    <json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.util.List" encoding="UTF-8" doc:name="JSON2ObjectList"/>
    <collection-splitter doc:name="Collection Splitter"/>
    <choice doc:name="Choice">
        <when expression="#[payload.Warehouse == &quot;a&quot;]">
            <custom-transformer ../>
        </when>
        <when expression="#[payload.Warehouse == &quot;b&quot;]">
            <custom-transformer ../>
        </when>
    </choice>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I suppose this will do the trick once I get the MEL expression right (now it gives me a java Nullpointer exception, telling me that the payload is a java.util.LinkedHashMap from the Collection splitter)